# Visual Studio fails to instantiate cast (conversion) operator template (T=bool) in the context of boolean operations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Why do Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 fail to compile this code?

Codepad.org, Xcode, gcc, LLVM, Clang all have no problem but Visual Studio poops the bed:

```
struct S {
  template <class T> inline operator T () const { return T (); }
};
int main () {
  // NOTE: "S()" denotes construction in these examples
  struct F {
    void operator() (bool) { }
    static void toint (int) { }
    static void tostr (char const*) { }
  };
  bool b1 = S (); // Okay
  bool b2 (S ()); // Okay
  F () (S ());    // Okay
  F::toint (S ());// Okay
  F::tostr (S ());// Okay

  S () || false;  // Error: error C2676: binary '||' : 'vf::S' does
                  // not define this operator or a conversion to a type
                  // acceptable to the predefined operator
  return 0;
}
```

Adding the `explicit` keyword doesn't change a thing for gcc or clang. The error message produced is:

```
error C2676: binary '||' : 'S' does not define this operator or a
  conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Comment: And the error message is...?

Comment: You could stick the cast in there.

Comment: in my 2012: Error 1 error C2676: binary '||' : 'S' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: Exactly:
binary '||': 'S' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: http://codepad.org/vupdcWdi

Works in Codepad (and everywhere else).

Comment: A bug, likely. I see no reason for this to fail.

Comment: chris: Sure, adding a cast would make it work but this is simplified code. In production code, the conversion could be invoked from an outer template and then it's not clear at the point of call to what the programmer should cast it to. This works on every other compiler...

Comment: *What* conversion should it perform? You have a type that can convert to *anything*, and there are several types that are defined for ||. So what type should it convert to?

Comment: @VinnieFalco: The fact that "This works on every other compiler" is completely irrelevant to whether it's a bug or not. What defines a bug is whether the *standard* allows it.

Comment: @Nicol: Since operator || converts both sides to bool, it is expected that S::operator bool () is invoked. This is completely unambiguous.

Comment: Caribou: operator() is not defined in my code example.

Comment: More interestingly, GCC ad Clang even accept this if the conversion operator is marked _explicit_ (note that Codepad is gcc and XCode is clang)

Comment: Caribou: Can you please post a codepad snippet?

Comment: Caribou: Right. In my code snippet, "S()" is a constructor call. In your code snippet replace "s()" with "s".

Comment: @VinnieFalco sorry - just experimenting and missed the point.

Comment: Caribou: It was easily confused. I updated the code sample to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Please report an issue on [Microsoft Connect](connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), or, if you'd prefer not to, let me know and I can open a bug.  Thanks!

Comment: Would you post a link to the bug, for future reference?

Comment: Sure, here it is:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771509/correct-code-doesnt-compile

Comment: Only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs not in c++11

Comment: @sehe Wow, now learned something! :O thx

Comment: I updated the original code example to show that the context of the bug is limited to bool conversion in the context of logical operators.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug, at least in C++03 (not sure about C++11).

According to the overload resolution rules in C++03 §13.3.1.2, the built-in `||` operator is selected, since no user-defined `||` operator is defined for `S`.

§5.15/1 says:

> The `||` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both implicitly converted to `bool` (clause 4). [...]

§12.3/2 says:

> User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous (10.2, 12.3.2). [...]

§12.3/5:

> User-defined conversions are used implicitly only if they are unambiguous.  [...] Function overload resolution (13.3.3) selects the best conversion function to perform the conversion.

§13.3.2/3:

> Second, for `F` to be a viable function, there shall exist for each argument an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1) that converts that argument to the corresponding parameter of `F`.

Clearly `S` defines a user-defined conversion to `bool`.  The built-in `||` operator is a viable function for the overload resolution, and since it's the only one, it's the best.  So the expression is well-formed.

Also of note is §4/3, which says:

> An expression `e` can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if the declaration “`T t=e;`” is well- formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). [...]

So I'm curious whether Visual Studio also produces an error for the statement `bool b = S();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you forbit implicit typecasting to boolean, the compiler has to check if there is an operator|| defined wich takes a boolean. This is (hopefully!) not defined because it would break shortcuts. So he has to check if there is an conversion-operator defined that gives it something defined for the global ||-operator. Could you solve this problem by adding a conversion-operator to bool, BOOL or int (wich is the same anyway^^)…?

`operator bool() {return this != null && this != 0xcccccccc;}`

This BTW would be just a hack, it would be better to provide a logical meaningful conversion.

Im shure there is a constant defined for 0xcccccccc marking uninitialized Memory in debug mode, but i dont know it.

Comment: This workaround would fix the sample code but is not usable in practice. The class in question represents a Lua type, which can take on any of 11 different actual types. If I were to provide conversion operators for bool, int, double, string, etc... then there would be ambiguous conversions. That's why I used the template.

The only real workaround is to provide a function:

    template <class T> T cast ()

and call it explicitly.